# Webpack Federated module's Production build fails with "Self-reference dependency has unused export name" when importing lodash

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

My webpack.config for a federated module, has multiple entries.

```js
entry: {
   "@namespace": "path/to/public_path_util.js",
   "namespace-worker-chunk-name1": "path/to/worker_public_path_util.js",
   "namespace-worker-chunk-name2": "path/to/worker_public_path_util.js",
   "namespace-worker-chunk-name3": "path/to/worker_public_path_util.js",
}
```

The first defines the mechanism by which federated modules instantiate the `__webpack_public_path__` for usage in the main application. If only this entry is provided, the production webpack build **does not fail**.

The next entries that were recently added define how webworker chunk names will initialize the `__webpack_public_path__` when they are instantiated from code. When these entries are defined, the development mode builds function normally and I was able to take advantage of web workers. My production build now fails with

```bash
ERROR in ./node_modules/lodash/_nodeUtil.js
Self-reference dependency has unused export name: This should not happen
Error: Self-reference dependency has unused export name: This should not happen
    at CommonJsSelfReferenceDependencyTemplate.apply (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/CommonJsSelfReferenceDependency.js:102:10)
    at JavascriptGenerator.sourceDependency (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptGenerator.js:206:12)
    at JavascriptGenerator.sourceModule (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptGenerator.js:112:9)
    at JavascriptGenerator.generate (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptGenerator.js:98:8)
    at NormalModule.codeGeneration (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1205:22)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3329:22
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:16:12
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:93:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/workspace/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:75:18)
    at ItemCacheFacade.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:111:15)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:50:53
    at next (/workspace/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:14:3)
    at forEachBail (/workspace/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:24:9)
    at MultiItemCache.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:50:3)
    at Compilation._codeGenerationModule (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3322:9)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3229:11
    at arrayIterator (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3467:9)
    at timesSync (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2297:7)
    at Object.eachLimit (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3463:5)
    at runIteration (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3209:13)
    at Compilation._runCodeGenerationJobs (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3284:3)
    at Compilation.codeGeneration (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3191:8)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3018:11
    at eval (eval at create (/workspace/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:23:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
 @ ./node_modules/lodash/isTypedArray.js 3:15-37
 @ ./node_modules/lodash/isEmpty.js 8:19-44
 @ ./teams/feature/component/src/module/ComponentName.jsx 1:343-379 1:1293-1300 1:1311-1318
 @ ./teams/feature/component/src/Application.jsx 1:500-565 2:601-616
 @ ./teams/feature/component/src/index.js 1:26-57 1:99-106
 @ container entry

ERROR in ./node_modules/lodash/isBuffer.js
Self-reference dependency has unused export name: This should not happen
Error: Self-reference dependency has unused export name: This should not happen
    at CommonJsSelfReferenceDependencyTemplate.apply (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/CommonJsSelfReferenceDependency.js:102:10)
    at JavascriptGenerator.sourceDependency (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptGenerator.js:206:12)
    at JavascriptGenerator.sourceModule (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptGenerator.js:112:9)
    at JavascriptGenerator.generate (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptGenerator.js:98:8)
    at NormalModule.codeGeneration (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1205:22)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3329:22
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:16:12
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:93:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/workspace/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:75:18)
    at ItemCacheFacade.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:111:15)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:50:53
    at next (/workspace/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:14:3)
    at forEachBail (/workspace/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:24:9)
    at MultiItemCache.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:50:3)
    at Compilation._codeGenerationModule (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3322:9)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3229:11
    at arrayIterator (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3467:9)
    at done (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3527:9)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3243:8
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3352:32
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/workspace/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.store (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:107:20)
    at ItemCacheFacade.store (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:137:15)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3352:11
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:93:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/workspace/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:75:18)
    at ItemCacheFacade.get (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:111:15)
    at Compilation._codeGenerationModule (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3322:9)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3229:11
    at arrayIterator (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3467:9)
    at timesSync (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2297:7)
    at Object.eachLimit (/workspace/project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3463:5)
    at runIteration (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3209:13)
    at Compilation._runCodeGenerationJobs (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3284:3)
    at Compilation.codeGeneration (/workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3191:8)
    at /workspace/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3018:11
    at eval (eval at create (/workspace/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:23:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
 @ ./node_modules/lodash/isEmpty.js 6:15-36
 @ ./teams/feature/component/src/module/ComponentName.jsx 1:343-379 1:1293-1300 1:1311-1318
 @ ./teams/feature/component/src/Application.jsx 1:500-565 2:601-616
 @ ./teams/feature/component/src/index.js 1:26-57 1:99-106
 @ container entry
```

Is this issue specific to configuring lodash modules to be included in my modules? Is there a configuration or transformation I need to include to make this work in production?

I'm on webpack 5.80.0

I've tried adding

```js
optimization: {
  sideEffects: false
}
```

and `sideEffects: true` with no effect on the build.

Comment: I do see it coming from https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/23c39437617d5ff8de4120911e728b0f56a5fed5/lib/dependencies/CommonJsSelfReferenceDependency.js#L119